# Modified Takeuchi function as non recursive function

Tags: functions, recursion

The [Takeuchi function](https://planetmath.org/TakeuchiFunction) is described as

$$
t(x,y,z) =
\begin{cases}
\text{if } x \leq y & y \\
\text{else} &  t⁢(t⁢(x-1,y,z),t⁢(y-1,z,x),t⁢(z-1,x,y)) \\
\end{cases}
$$

which also has a non-recursive definition:

$$
t(x,y,z) =
\begin{cases}
\text{if } x \leq y & y \\
\text{else if } y \leq z&  z \\
\text{else } &  x \\
\end{cases}
$$

Now the problem: I am trying to work out the non-recursive definition of a modified version which is the following:

$$
t(x,y,z) =
\begin{cases}
\text{if } x \leq z & y \\
\text{else} &  t⁢(t⁢(x-1,y,z),t⁢(y-1,z,x),t⁢(z-1,x,y)) \\
\end{cases}
$$

My first approach was to order the input in lexicographical order (starting at $t(1,1,1))$ and trying to deduce a relationship which seemed to look like like this initially:

$$
t(x,y,z) =
\begin{cases}
\text{if } x \leq z & y \\
\text{else if } y > x &  x \\
\text{else } &  z \\
\end{cases}
$$

but that does not work, a counterexample is t(20, 7, 18)=8. So the underlying relationship seems to be a bit more complex. I have also tried to formally infer the solution by differentiating the cases for the '>'-relation between the variables but I did not get far with that either.